Magento API speed?
We are trying to do API product import into Magento and getting out such performances:
Threads = 3 ( no web lags )
60min = 806 sku
CPU load = 22-25%
Threads = 10 ( web starts to lag )
60min = 1465
CPU load = 35-39%
Threads = 20 ( web lag, a lot )
60min =  1523
CPU load = 38-40%
The point is, that we have millions of products(dealing with car parts). It will take 1333h to upload 2,000,000 SKU, which is 2 months.
Is there any way how we can speed up API calls? Adding more threads does not speed up, CPU load stays at 40% and does not go UP.
Server data:
Regular Intel 8 vCPUs  16 GB 160 GB 6 TB.
I'm asking because found guys who offer plugin which can push 2500 SKU per minute with half server power as we are using.
Interesting how they achieved these speeds:
https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html
Any tips please?

That's correct. So the best way to import product is directly to database.

Are you saying the answer is correct? Please accept the answer if so. This is not a discussion forum, so commenting here does nothing.

Your limitation here is that you are using the REST API to add/update each product, which generates a transaction for each call. That call will trigger the update on the indexes, transactions on the database and cache clearing that uses resources from the server to be completed. This is limiting the amount of calls you can do at the same time. The usage does not goes up as the resources can only be used by one thread at the time when blocked for writing.
When using an extension like the one you mention, they are doing bulk updates/adding on the database within one transaction and then triggering the process of cache flush, update indexes, etc.... only one time after importing all the records at once. This is more efficient that updating one by one!
If using the modules is not an alternative, you might be able to use the bulk endpoints ( see https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/use-rest/bulk-endpoints/ ) which allow to send the product information on bulk and then the background workers will pickup the work to do secuentially. Not as fast as the import process via de module but you might be able to play with the queue workers on background to process the data faster.
Hope that helps to improve your import time!
